# Вывод товара в корзине php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с отображением корзины
Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на ссылку, перейдя на cart.php отображало информацию в таблице о выбранном товаре?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это файл отображающий каталог:

```
<?php 
//require "functions/function.php";

session_start();
$biskvits = all_biskvit();

//require 'functions/connect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    $_SESSION['total_items'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['total_price'] = '0.00';
}


//Если нажата кнопка Добавить
if (isset($_POST['add-to-cart-button'])) {
  add_to_cart();
  redirect();
}

?> 

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Учёт заказов для кондитерского цеха</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
<div class="fon1">

<h1><div style="margin-left: 608px">Добро пожаловать, Пользователь!</div></h1>

<?php require 'inc/menu_p.php'; ?>
<div style="padding: 3%; background-color: #faebd7">
    <?php if($biskvits):?>
        <?php foreach ($biskvits as $biskvit) :?>
<div class="product-wrap">
  <div class="product-image">
    <?php if(empty($biskvit['img'])):?>
        <a href=""><img src="/images/no_photo.jpg"></a>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if(!empty($biskvit['img'])):?>
        <a href=""><img src="/images/<?=$biskvit['img']?>"></a>
    <?php endif;?>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="actions">
      <div class="actions-btn">
        <div class="add-to-cart">
          <a class="add-to-cart-button" href="cart.php?view=add_to_cart&kod_biskvita=<?=$biskvit['kod_biskvita']?>" title="Добавить в корзину"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="add-to-links">
          <div class="quikview">

      <div class="cd-item-info" style="font-size: 16px;  background-color: #faebd7; margin-left: 15px;">
          <p  style=" color: #b55489"><?=$biskvit['opisanie']?></p>
      </div> <!-- cd-item-info -->
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="product-list">
    <h3 style="color:#db7093" name="nazvanie" value=""><?=$biskvit['nazvanie']?></h3>
    <p>Вес: <?=$biskvit['ves']?> кг</p>
    <?php $biskvit['price'] = $biskvit['price'] * $biskvit['ves'];?>
    <div class="price">&#8381; <?=$biskvit['price']?></div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
</div>

<?php
switch($view)
{
case('add_to_cart'):
  $kod_biskvita = $_GET['kod_biskvita'];
  $add_item = add_to_cart($kod_biskvita);
  header('Location: index.php?view=glav_p&kod_biskvita'.$kod_biskvita);
break;
}
?>

 </body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл корзины:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Учёт заказов для кондитерского цеха</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
<?php require 'inc/menu_p.php'; ?>

<h1 align="center">Ваша корзина</h1>

<?php
if($_SESSION['cart'] != '0')
{   
?>

<form action="" method="post" id="cart-form">

<table id="mycart" align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th> Товар </th>
            <th> Цена </th> 
            <th> Количество </th>
            <th> Всего </th>
    </tr>


    <?php foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $kod_biskvita => $quantity): 
        $product = get_product($kod_biskvita);
        ?>

    <tr>
        <td align="center"><?=$product['nazvanie']; ?></td> 
        <td align="center"><?=$product['price']; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="2" name="<?=$kod_biskvita;?>" maxlength="2" value="<?=$quantity;?>" /></td> 
        <td align="center"><?=$product['price'] * $quantity; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?endforeach;?>

</table>
    <p class="total" align="center">Общая сумма заказа: <span class="product-price">руб.</span></p>

</form>     

<?
}
else
{
    echo "Ваша корзина пуста!";
}
```

Функция:

```
function add_to_cart($kod_biskvita)
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart']['kod_biskvita']))
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$kod_biskvita]++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$kod_biskvita] = 1;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Возможно, на странице с корзиной не стартуется сессия. Соответственно товаров в ней нет

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['card']); как минимум для ясности